# Oracle Apex/ORDS REST service does not POST data correctly using curl - All fields null

Tags: rest, curl, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am using Oracle Apex 20.2.0.00.20 and ORDS to test a first REST service using [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/report-and-form-on-a-rest-service:-low-code-with-apex-191) tutorial. Instead of the table in the tutorial I used the `emp` table. It works until the point where I try to `POST` data to the REST service using `curl`.

I can successfully `GET` the url `https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/emp/` and it returns the row JSON.

I used this `curl` command from the DOS prompt using `curl` for DOS to `POST` data:

```
curl -X POST -H'Content-Type:application/json' -d'{"ename":"JUSTIN","job":"ANALYST","mgr":7839,"hiredate":"2020-04-30T22:00:00Z","sal":100000,"comm":null,"deptno":30}' https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/emp/
```

This creates a row in the `emp` table, but all the table columns are null except for the `empno` column which gets populated via a trigger.

The output from `curl` is:

```
{"empno":8003,"ename":null,"job":null,"mgr":null,"hiredate":null,"sal":null,"comm":null,"deptno":null,"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/emp/8003"},{"rel":"edit","href":"https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/emp/8003"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/metadata-catalog/emp/item"},{"rel":"collection","href":"https://myserver:8080/apex/mydb/myschema/emp/"}]}
```

Also when I send through a `job` that exceeds the column length it does not fail with status 500, but instead creates the row with nulls again.

Anybody know where the tutorial or I are going wrong?

Comment: I remember using this example: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql#create-post-web-services It worked for me like charm...

Comment: Thanks, but looking for Apex automated; and it does not mention Apex 20.2

Comment: How is this related to a specific apex version ? ORDS and Apex are different technologies. What you're trying to do is unrelated to apex (at least your example shows no relationship with apex)

Comment: The "Web Source Modules" in the tutorial is where it becomes Apex related - what you're trying to do here: a POST to a restful service is ORDS related and does not need apex. You could try running it using a browser extension like Postman instead of using curl (which is a challenge on windows).

Comment: So you're using AutoREST table. If you open sql developer web, the REST console gives your the cURL cmd for your post https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/01/oracle-sql-developer-web-20-4-and-autorest/

Comment: I want to build a REST interface with Apex, which certainly should be possible and secondly should be easy. How to do this has however changed between different Apex versions. I don't have SQL Developer Web, I have Apex. I could not find a tutorial for my version of Apex, but one would think if you click REST enable table that it should do what it says.

Comment: As in the tutorial it shows not AutoREST enabled for my table. There are no options to enable this that I saw and it does not mention it in the tutorial. I am interested in a simple, no code solution.

Comment: @Superdooperhero if you have ords, you have sqldev-web. The rest interface in apex doesn't have as many features, but you're free to use it if course

Comment: That tutorial is using AutoREST. Maybe it would help if you showed us exactly what you're doing instead of referencing links.